# Lenovo G50-80 without battery

Tags: lenovo-laptop, battery-life, charging

Can I run my laptop G50-80(with li-ion battery) only on AC power without battery to prolong battery life-time? Is there any problem if I do so continuously?

Comment: Not that I know. After some months it should be advisable to charge the battery. The only risk I see is that you might forget where you stored the battery ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you pull the battery - most laptops can survive on just AC.

If you want to prolong battery life, bring the battery down to about 30% charge (doesn't have to be exact). This is the storage state of the battery, where it is safest stored without being damaged. Storing at a full charge will not prolong the battery life any longer than leaving it in - at a full charge the cells deteriorate quickly.

The disadvantage to this is that if you ever need the battery, you will need to (should) bring it to a full charge before using it.

Some people in the radio controlled vehicle community store their batteries in a warm fridge, at storage charge. I've never done this - research it before you do anything.